# Rails integration test headers not being set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-headers, integration-testing

```
@request.headers["Authorization"] = "Token token=#{auth_token}"
post "/verify"
```

When I `puts @request.inspect` the only headers I see are:

```
..."action_controller.instance"=>
#<VerificationsController:0x007fc5683ebd38 @_routes=nil, 
@_action_has_layout=true, 
@_headers={"Content-Type"=>"text/html"}...
```

Why is my authorization header not showing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up getting this to work:

```
headers = { 'Authorization' => "Token token=\"#{auth_token}\"" } 
json_body = {}
post "api/1.1/cartwheelregister/verify/answers", json_body, headers
```